# Isolated storage - opeation not permitted / while copying html file in Windows Phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone, isolatedstorage

When I run

```
IsolatedStorageFile myStore = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
myStore.CopyTextFile("HTDocs\\help.html", true);
```

I have error: "Operation not permitted on IsolatedStorageFileStream." It's from [tutorial](http://technodave.wordpress.com/2010/11/11/moving-files-from-xap-to-isolated-storage-for-local-html-content-on-windows-phone-7/). How should I fix that?

```
public static class ISExtensions
    {
        public static void CopyTextFile(this IsolatedStorageFile isf, string filename, bool replace = false)
        {
            if (!isf.FileExists(filename) || replace == true)
            {
                StreamReader stream = new StreamReader(TitleContainer.OpenStream(filename));

                IsolatedStorageFileStream outFile = isf.CreateFile(filename);
                //

                //
                string fileAsString = stream.ReadToEnd();
                byte[] fileBytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(fileAsString);

                outFile.Write(fileBytes, 0, fileBytes.Length);

                stream.Close();
                outFile.Close();
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: Are you executing this method across multiple threads?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```cs
// isolated storage
IsolatedStorageFile myStore = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
// access to resource files
StreamResourceInfo streamInfo = Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri(@"HTDocs\help.html", UriKind.Relative));
using (Stream origFileStream = streamInfo.Stream)
{
    // open the filestream for the isostorage file and copy the content from the original stream
    using (IsolatedStorageFileStream fileStream = myStore.CreateFile("help.html"))
    {
        origFileStream.CopyTo(fileStream);
        origFileStream.Close();
    }
}
```